# Change behavior of clean_names (janitor) to remove underscore

Tags: r, janitor

I am cleaning names of a data frame from an imported XLS file that is named `Concentration \n(ng/mL)`:

```
test_data <- tibble(
  subject = 1,
  `Concentration \n(ng/mL)` = 10
)

test_data_clean <- janitor::clean_names(test_data)

names(test_data_clean)

[1] "subject"              "concentration_ng_m_l"
```

How do I change the behavior of clean_names so that it outputs the following instead?

```
concentration_ng_ml
```

clean_names seems to be interpreting the upper case "L" after a lower case "m". Is there any way to change this rule?

Comment: You can specify a named character vector where the name is replaced by the vector. So using `janitor::clean_names(test_data, replace = c("mL" = "ml"))` should give you the desired name. Alternatively, you could experiment with different `case` arguments. For example, using `janitor::clean_names(test_data, case = "none")` would give you `Concentration_ng_mL` if you didn't want all true snake case.

Comment: Using `replace = c("mL" = "ml")` worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Ben that is an ideal solution.  Would you post it as an answer so the question can be closed?

Comment: @SamFirke Sure - happy to. I really appreciate your package!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a named character vector where the name is replaced by the vector. So you could try the following:

```
library(janitor)

clean_names(test_data, replace = c("mL" = "ml")) 

  subject concentration_ng_ml
    <dbl>               <dbl>
1       1                  10
```

Alternatively, you could experiment with different `case` arguments. For example, you can use `case = "none"`:

```
clean_names(test_data, case = "none") 

  subject Concentration_ng_mL
    <dbl>               <dbl>
1       1                  10
```

This might be a good option if you didn't want all true snake case.